# Where can I easily browse high-quality, free and recent photos?

Tags: flickr, internet

I suppose this isn't about photography so much as the online distribution of photos.

The gist: I'm looking for an online source for a robust catalog of free and high-quality color photos taken within the past decade or so. Flickr demands I do too much clicking-thru to determine if a photo is available, and its max size/resolution is on the low end of what I'm looking for. Google Image search is also insufficient, as it's polluted with junk. Any ideas?

Thanks! SB

Comment: Why was this question voted down? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: @Sam What is the "free" you are looking for?

Comment: This is off-topic.

Comment: Hi Sam. As stated, this kind of question is off-topic here.

Comment: Not off-topic in my mind. I think this question is valid.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect most photographers will be twitching uncomfortably at your request for "free" photos: everyone seems to want to use other people's work for free these days. :-\

However, without trying to second-guess your motives it's a valid enough question. Most high-quality photos you find online will be under copyright, meaning you can't re-use them for any purpose without the copyright owner's permission. However, have you discovered the [Creative Commons area on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/)? If people are kind enough to license their work in this way then you're actively encouraged to use it accordingly. Flickr's [advanced search page](http://www.flickr.com/search/advanced/) lets you limit your search to CC-licensed material taken within the last *n* years, although there's no way to filter by maximum image size.

Other than that, all I can suggest is you pick up a camera and get out shooting. :)

Answer (score 1):

you will find some photos here:
http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/
which have very free Public Domain license.

or try [Deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/), there are some photos with a free license, which can be used as stock photo, but they are mostly limited to noncommercial use.

and as I know, all photos made by U.S. government employees are licensed under Public Domain -  for example photos by U.S. army.